# Angularjs $http get fails, but request is succesful in postman and browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, adobe, typekit

I'm trying to access the Adobe TypeKit API's via javascript, using AngularJS. 
Using `$http.get(https://typekit.com/api/v1/json/kits?token=myToken)` fails on authenticated requests, with error: 
`No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.`

If I use `$http.jsonp(...)` un-authenticated requests are succesfull, this is probably due to Adobe's CORS policies, but as stated in the typekit documentation

> For security reasons, authenticated API requests are currently unavailable with callbacks.

So, using jsonp, I can't access many of the endpoints provided by the API's.
What I don't understand is that the same exact request that fails in angular, succeds if I execute it with postman or with chrome itself. I tryied setting the request headers exactly the same as in postman, but didn't work. Tried all sorts of headers settings, but nothing changed. 
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

can you disable the chrome web security and then give it a try.To disable the web security open your terminal and type the following /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --disable-web-security --allow-file-access-from-files --allow-file-access --user-data-dir=~/chrome-test/ spec/runner.html

Comment: I don't know why, I don't know how, but it works, although I need to set a header: `{'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}`

Comment: what does this mean? and how can I replicate this without having to run chrome without web security?

Comment: Is it working fine when web security is disabled?Please refer to this question for more details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource

Comment: Thanks for your reference, the only thing htat helped me was using cors.io, I will go with that, but I'm still looking for a better solution, since I'm not too happy with this one.